# Python does not match regex check

Tags: python, regex

I am using code below:

```
import re

destination_nat = "Disabled rules are not shown\nCodes: X - exclude rule\n\nrule    intf              translation                                               \n----    ----              -----------                                               \n1       eth0              daddr 172.27.59.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24                    \n        proto-all         dport ANY"
destination_split = destination_nat.split("\n")


for item in destination_split:

    test = re.findall(r'\d+.\s+eth\d\s+daddr', item)


print(test)
```

But get no result in test.

When i replace the variabele 'item' in the findall string with the the text of the specific line i get a result.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `destination_nat.split("\\n")` or `destination_nat.split(r"\n")`

Comment: Your the best, \\n was the solution :)

Comment: Did you mean to put `print(test)` within the for loop? Otherwise you will only print the results for the last line item of `destination_split` (which does match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below :

```
import re

destination_nat = "Disabled rules are not shown\nCodes: X - exclude rule\n\nrule    intf              translation                                               \n----    ----              -----------                                               \n1       eth0              daddr 172.27.59.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24                    \n        proto-all         dport ANY"
destination_split = destination_nat.split("r'\n")


for item in destination_split:

    test = re.findall(r'\d+.\s+eth\d\s+daddr', item)


print(test)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the only effect of `destination_nat.split("r'\n")` seems to be to cause it not to actually split `destination_nat`. You could get the same result with `destination_split = [destination_nat]`